# How do I verify ISTQB certificate of a person

Tags: interview, istqb, certification

Some strange thing is happening. I have a CV of a candidate for taking position in my project. They state they have `ISTQB certificate` and provide certificate number. But I'm not able to find any information about how to verify if the certificate is valid.

I've searched around the Internet and all the results I get refer to the examination and courses providers (likely because of their well work in `SEO domain`), but no results saying how to verify the issued certificate.

The most relevant resource I managed to find is http://scr.istqb.org but it declares that it keeps only ones issued not earlier than in years `2018-2017` (and even there is quite a small probability to find the required cert for 2k17).

I do not believe such a huge certification business does not provide some single-point verification resource, that would be reliable and comprehensive. I do likely miss some searching skills.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're trying to verify the applicant's certification rather than the knowledge you expect the applicant to have because of the certification? With a few questions you should be able to assess whether or not someone actually knows the material or not...

Comment: Yes, there is. This is called pre-screening. Not to waste time to organize the interview. This is the effective approach when you have a lot of CV to review.

Comment: Wow.. that seems like a lot of work to me.. do you receive a lot of applications with false credentials? I've never had any reason to believe that applicants that I interviewed were being dishonest about that.

Comment: I always do some quick fact-checking preliminary. Candidates like to draw more beautiful pictures than the real state of things or to tell a half-truth. So I would be happy to have a quick ISTQB validation to make the process autonomous like, say, you have with SSL certs validation. I do believe there would be nearly zero percent false-cred. but checking the cert validity is at least fair in relation to those who invested a lot of effort and money to get a valid certificate.

Comment: Although not your question: I would focus on things you really want to know from you candidates. In my experience having certificates (legit ones) don't tell me much in real life...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ask for the link through which he has downloaded the certificate because that is a unique link which is receive on completion of the certificate.

I am an ISQTB certified tester through the ISQI German Board, so I have received the link from their email address to download the certificate and that is an official link. You could easily identify.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the candidates certificate number, their candidate number or registration number, and it was awarded by BCS... you can check the validity [here](https://eprofessional.bcs.org/Portal/eCertCheck).

Answer (score 2):

This suggests that you should be able to get more information through an ISTQB Member Board:

https://www.istqb.org/exams-root/counterfeit-certificate-warning.html

> To verify the authenticity of your ISTQB® certificate or ISTQB® Exam Provider, or if you are suspicious about the way any training or exams are conducted, please contact the ISTQB® Member Board nearest to you, providing details of the certificate and of the Exam/ Training Provider.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be quite tricky though :( I thought there should have been some more time-effective way.

Comment: The passage you quite isn't about certificates but about *certificate providers* meaning places where you can obtain certification.

Comment: @AlexeyR. you're welcome, I guess they are working on such a platform with the link you provided yourself. I'm surprised how easy it is to get a list of people named John with a certificate.

Comment: @Cronax the first words of the quote are "To verify the authenticity of your ISTQB® certificate".

Comment: @PieterA 'you can read it as To verify the authenticity of your (ISTQB® certificate or ISTQB® Exam) Provider'. Not sure that's what they mean, but yay@language ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link for Foundation:
http://www.istqb.in/istqb-foundation/foundationnew#

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely very useful. This is for those how look up for the testers certified in India.

Comment: Wow, it's not often I remove a flag on a link only answer to a year old question, but I guess this is the exception to the rule! :-)

Answer (score 0):

With privacy regulations such GDPR, it's not surprising that you would need to check with the ISTQB member board. For those who live in the U.S. or work for a U.S. company, you can search the official certification list of the American Software Testing Qualifications Board (ASTQB, ISTQB in the U.S.) at:

https://www.astqb.org/sections/list-of-certified-testers.php

Answer (score 0):

You can search with the below link. Here you can search by name or certificate number.

http://scr.istqb.org/

Sample result like below :

[image]

Comment: That's what was mentioned in the initial question. Along with information that candidates who obtained a certificate before January 2017 may not be listed. The site says it as well. So the actual question was how to search even for certificates issued before 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can check/verify the authenticity of certificate issues by ISTQB BCS via below link

https://eprofessional.bcs.org/Portal/eCertCheck